# PL/SQL procedure to insert id to rows having same information

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have contact details data in Oracle table something like below...

[image: INPUT]

I want to insert new column to assign same ID to the contacts having matching information , i.e. based on group of lastname, firstname and (phone and/or email)

Output should look like below

[image: OUTPUT]

I'm new to this forum, so having formatting issues while posting question, please see attached images for easy understanding of my requirement

Looking for PL/SQL procedure to get this done in our huge database

Comment: can you share sample data  here so that I can try query on local  . it help really help

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure? A simple `rank()` will do

Comment: Always post sample data in table format as text not as image

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can you please provide me solution if you think rank() will solve my purpose.  I was thinking for procedue because data is complicated, for example you see in my sample output requirement for ID 2, there are multiple combinations of phone and email. For same total 13 first name last name,  these are actually only 4 distinct contacts as you can analyse the combinations in the given sample output.

Comment: LAST_NAME FIRST_NAME PHONE EMAIL ID
Ho Kim 2058371579 ABC@GMAIL.COM 1
Ho Kim 4479940000 ABC@GMAIL.COM 1
Ho Kim 7195739945 XYZ@HOTMAIL.COM 2
Ho Kim 7475393956 XYZ@HOTMAIL.COM 2
Ho Kim 7475393956 XYZ@HOTMAIL.COM 2
Ho Kim 7473430336  3
Ho Kim 7195739945 XYZ@HOTMAIL.COM 2
Ho Kim 7475393956 123@HOTMAIL.COM 2
Ho Kim  123@HOTMAIL.COM 2
Ho Kim 1168548666 456@HOTMAIL.COM 4
Ho Kim 1168548666 456@HOTMAIL.COM 4
Ho Kim 1168548666  4
Ho Kim 7473430336  3

Comment: What if you have chains?  Id 1 has the same phone number as Id2.  Id2 has the same email as Id3.  Id3 has the same phone number as Id4.  What are the results then?

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes this is the exact issue and I want same ID for such chain. Can you provide me with pl/sql procedure to insert/update IDs ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a site where you can ask questions and get answers about problems you're having with software you've written, but it is not a "do my homework for me" or "do my job for me" site. When you ask a question you should include the code you've written and the specific errors you're getting or the results your program produces and an explanation of the results you expected. Without that there's really not much we can do to help you. Please edit your question to show what you've done and tell us what problems the code has. Again, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the nature of the data you presented I see no possible way to do it in one SQL or for it to be better tuned.

Script to create the table and populate with your example:

```
create table TAB_TEST(LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(200),
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(200),
PHONE NUMBER,
EMAIL VARCHAR2(200))
/
INSERT INTO TAB_TEST VALUES
('Ho','Kim', 2058371579, 'ABC@GMAIL.COM')
/
INSERT INTO TAB_TEST VALUES
('Ho','Kim', 4479940000, 'ABC@GMAIL.COM')
/
INSERT INTO TAB_TEST VALUES
('Ho','Kim', 7195739945, 'XYZ@HOTMAIL.COM')
/
INSERT INTO TAB_TEST VALUES
('Ho','Kim', 7475393956, 'XYZ@HOTMAIL.COM')
/
INSERT INTO TAB_TEST VALUES
('Ho','Kim', 7475393956, 'XYZ@HOTMAIL.COM')
/
INSERT INTO TAB_TEST VALUES
('Ho','Kim', 7473430336, null)
/
INSERT INTO TAB_TEST VALUES
('Ho','Kim', 7195739945, 'XYZ@HOTMAIL.COM')
/
INSERT INTO TAB_TEST VALUES
('Ho','Kim', 7475393956, '123@HOTMAIL.COM')
/
INSERT INTO TAB_TEST VALUES
('Ho','Kim', null, '123@HOTMAIL.COM')
/
INSERT INTO TAB_TEST VALUES
('Ho','Kim', 1168548666, '456@HOTMAIL.COM')
/
INSERT INTO TAB_TEST VALUES
('Ho','Kim', 1168548666, '456@HOTMAIL.COM')
/
INSERT INTO TAB_TEST VALUES
('Ho','Kim', 1168548666, null)
/
INSERT INTO TAB_TEST VALUES
('Ho','Kim', 7473430336, null)
/
ALTER TABLE TAB_TEST ADD ID NUMBER
/
```

And the script to update

```
DECLARE 
lncount   NUMBER := 1; 

-- had to create this record in order to add the rowid
TYPE lttab_test IS RECORD( 
  ROWID VARCHAR2(200), 
  last_name VARCHAR2(200), 
  first_name VARCHAR2(200), 
  phone NUMBER, 
  email VARCHAR2(200), 
  id NUMBER); 

TYPE lttype 
  IS TABLE OF LTTAB_TEST; 

larecords LTTYPE; 
BEGIN 
SELECT ROWID, 
       last_name, 
       first_name, 
       phone, 
       email, 
       id 
bulk   collect INTO larecords 
FROM   tab_test a; 


FOR i IN 1..larecords.count LOOP 

    IF Larecords(i).id IS NULL THEN 
      FOR j IN 1..i-1 LOOP 
          IF Larecords(j).phone = Larecords(i).phone
             AND Larecords(i).id IS NULL THEN 
            Larecords(i).id := Larecords(j).id; 

            exit; 
          END IF; 
      END LOOP; 

      FOR j IN 1..i-1 LOOP 
          IF Larecords(j).email = Larecords(i).email 
             AND Larecords(i).id IS NULL THEN 
            Larecords(i).id := Larecords(j).id; 

            exit; 
          END IF; 
      END LOOP; 

      IF Larecords(i).id IS NULL THEN 
        Larecords(i).id := lncount; 

        lncount := lncount + 1; 
      END IF; 

    END IF; 
END LOOP; 

forall i IN 1..larecords.count 
  UPDATE tab_test 
  SET    id = Larecords(i).id 
  WHERE  ROWID = Larecords(i).ROWID; 

COMMIT:
END;
```

Comment: If you could mark my comment as being the answer it could help in the future for other people and I receive reputation. Thank you

Comment: your above code worked well on sample test data which was small but it fails when we process large amount of data. Can you please share the code with Bulk limit of  let's say 5 rows at a time in test data and that should generate same output.

Comment: The 'fors' make it slow and truth be told I don't know how to implement your issue into faster queries. Bulk wouldn't work because it always has to look at the previous status for the records.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't the most efficient / pretty code but it works in case you just want sequential numbers

```
DECLARE 
I NUMBER := 0;

BEGIN 
  ALTER TABLE TABLE 
  ADD ID NUMBER;
  COMMIT;

FOR REC IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE) 
  LOOP 
    IF(REC.ID IS NULL) THEN
      UPDATE TABLE T SET ID = I 
      WHERE (T.EMAIL = REC.EMAIL OR T.PHONE = REC.PHONE)
      AND ID IS NULL;
      COMMIT;
      I := I + 1;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: DDL automatically commits transaction, you don't need to use COMMIT.

Comment: TheName@ if you start a PL/SQL procedure from java, this might not always be the case

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: TheName@ creating a connection object in Java, using Connection.setAutoCommit to set autocommit to false, and then using Java Connection.prepareCall to call the stored procedure